# Civic duty badge at 299 votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, badges

Just got the Civic Duty badge at 299 votes, is that intentional?  Does it start counting at zero?

This is on SO btw.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When the badge was awarded to you, you had voted on 300 active posts - then one of the posts was deleted, taking your total down to 299.

Comment: update: since Feb 2012, votes on deleted posts are ["included in the profile counts. This will also apply to the various voting badges to match: Civic Duty, Electorate, Suffrage, Vox Populi..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/165773)