# Wrong number of downvotes in summary

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

In my profile I can see that I've cast 2 downvotes.

> [image: Votes Cast Summary]

But I am relatively sure that I've only downvoted one answer and I only see one entry in the "votes" category of my profile.

Is it possible that the summary is wrong?

Here is an image of my reputation history: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF0Rz.png

As you can see there, I have only one "downvoted" event in my entire history, and the "show removed posts" checkbox is enabled.

There is also only one downvote in my "votes"-list
[image: Votes list]

Comment: Is it possible that something you downvoted has been removed?

Comment: Maybe - but as I said, I'm relatively (99% at least) sure that I downvoted only once. But I can't totally exclude that I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your reputation graph and a link to the related question?

Comment: You may have down voted something that was then deleted.

Comment: @juergend: I added a link to the downvoted answer and I've uploaded a screenshot of my reputation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two downvotes, and your reputation indicates you have only ever downvoted one post, then the other downvote must be for a question.  Questions do not cost 1 rep to you when you downvote.

Comment: Shouldn't be the downvote for a question be visible in the "votes" list? There I can only see my downvote for the answer

Comment: @ChristopherBrix Not if that question was deleted.

Comment: @Christopher this was probably my fault: ["Votes cast" should include votes on deleted contributions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117846)

Comment: @ChristopherBrix No, pekka is referring to the fact that deleted posts didn't use to count in the summary, but he posted a feature request (which was accepted and has since been implemented) to allow posts that were downvoted and then deleted to still show in the summary.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suspect you downvoted a post that has since been removed. Check the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your reputation history and look through it again. You will probably find another `downvoted` entry, as well as a corresponding `removed` entry.

Comment: In the uploaded screenshot of my reputation history I already checked "show removed posts" but I still see only one downvoted answer