# Why is there difference in votes count between summary page and vote tab?

Tags: support, voting, vote-count

Why is there difference in votes count between summary page and vote tab?
See the images

[image]

Where

[image]

On the  summary page it is showing votes count 1131 that is (1090+41) fine and when i click on view more link it show me count 1109, why this difference...

Comment: First of all please don't compare both vote cast count because summary page shows only upvotes and downvotes while vote tab includes upvote,downvote, deletion, undelete, closure and reopen. But here problem is that votes cast count on vote tab should be greater that votes cast count on summary page.

Comment: @hims056 That's the point... 100% true, good observation

Comment: +1 In my case, In summary page, Vote cast count for upvotes is 1587 and for downvotes is 1062 while in my vote tab, Vote cast count for upvotes is 1570 and for downvotes is **only 465**. Very big difference.

Comment: It appears that the summary of up-votes and down-votes includes deleted answers. In my votes tab on SO, I see 1045 up-votes and 198 down-votes. In my summary I see 1067 up-votes and 321 down-votes. So that's 22 up-votes unaccounted for and 123 down-votes unaccounted for.

Comment: @hims056, oops didn't see you had that comment that is basically the same as mine. It wasn't there when I opened this page :). Anyway, one more data point agreeing with yours.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The votes count summary on your main profile page **includes deleted posts**. Going to your full votes list for your account does *not* list delete posts, nor include them in the count at the top.

For example, my summary says I've cast 1,861 votes (1,281 up and 580 down), but going to my voting page, it says I've cast 1,247 up and 353 down (totaling 1,600). So I can logically deduce that 261 of the posts I've voted on in the past have been deleted now.

This is most noticeable when viewing your delete votes (if you have the privilege to delete), which would show up empty if all the posts you've ever voted to delete did, in fact, get deleted.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I have 0 delete votes on SO. I was sure I had cast some at some point.

Comment: Is there any option like `show removed posts` for 10k+ users in vote tab?

Comment: @hims056: No, there's not. I'm sure there's a feature request for it somewhere. I remember a lot of people were complaining that the delete tab didn't make much sense if the votes disappeared when the post got deleted.