# Small issue with inconsistency of votes cast summary and detail votes tab in profile

Tags: support, bug, voting, recent-activity

When I look at my profile, I found there's an inconsistency of numbers in the summary shown at the page bottom, and the numbers shown in the details vote page:

Summary:
[image]

Detail page:
[image]

Why is that?
A mod explained it may come that deleted posts aren't counted at the detail page, can someone confirm please?

Also I find that at least confusing, is that intentional, and if yes why?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160628/369802 So yes it's intentional but that doesn't mention the why.

Comment: @tinker Yes, The _why_ is unfortunately missing.

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions#comment309145_117846 and search for text "visible on the site" here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/282094 --- After 60 days you keep, even if it's permanently deleted. --- Not easy to see the "dupe".

Comment: @Rob Ha, Nick again ;-). Yes, that's an acceptable reasoning (badges count, etc.). I'll mark my question as duplicate. Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the mod told you is true, the detailed page doesn't show deleted posts. So the total number in the detailed page is the count of posts you've voted on that haven't been deleted.

If you notice questions that have been deleted by Roomba won't be visible in the detailed list.

Some parts of the profile page work differently, look at your flagging history the deleted posts are shown marked in red.

Comment: Ty for the confirmation. I'd be interested in an explanation if that's intentional and why though. At least that should be documented, no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ unless there's a staff post somewhere explaining the reasons we don't know. But fact is, if you're checking your history of voted posts the results are a lot less polluted because the deleted posts are removed. In the flag history it's different, most of what you're flagging is bound to be closed or deleted, if they removed those links nothing would be left except the rejected flags.

Comment: Of course, I wanted a staff member to respond. At least that now marked duplicate gives good reasoning why it's implemented as is. Nick Craver who wrote the accepted answer, is one of the technical leads of SE's dev team.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I decided to take this question to celebrate my 1k (seeing vote count privilege). From what I gather the linked Q's don't address advantage/disadvantage of omitting results to reduce visual pollution. So the answer itself isn't a duplicate.