# What situations cause a "loss" of votes?

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-count

About a year ago, [the count of votes cast was changed so that it includes votes cast on closed questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions)  Prior to that, your vote count would go down when a question was closed.

Every now and then I'll notice that my total vote count has gone down and I'm trying to figure out why.  I'm guessing migrations, but I can't find anything that says one way or another if your vote count goes down when questions are migrated, and I can't think of any other situation when you'd "lose" votes.

Are there any (other) situations in which a person's vote count would go down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, your vote count goes down during a migration. Aside from that, the only other times it goes down (short of you reversing a vote yourself) is if you serially upvote someone and the votes get reversed.

Comment: What is voted post is deleted?

Comment: @AboobackerMk: No, they still count. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions