# Votes, deleted content and "Vote Early, Vote Often"

Tags: support, voting, vote-to-delete, winter-bash-2015

So, I vote on a lot of material. I also delete vote a fair bit of material that I've voted on too.

I know from experience that when you delete a post you have voted on within the same day, you get the vote 'refunded'.

I just want to verify that if I vote on exactly 250 posts in seven days and happen to delete one of them too, that its the 250 votes that count, not the 249 that are still in the system.

Just want to check on this sooner than later so that I don't suddenly find that I'm a few votes short of the hat after 7 days (and *then* try to figure out about if my math is wrong or if I have a reproducible bug).

P.S. The wording on the hat is a bit unclear - do close and delete votes count too? Or just up and down?

Comment: I was wondering about this too! Good question!

Comment: I think you should test this. For science.

Comment: "votes on deleted posts will be included in the profile counts.  This will also apply to the various voting badges to match: Civic Duty, Electorate, Suffrage, Vox Populi.  Also, the badge progress on review should remain accurate. Downvoting bad content (which usually ends up being deleted) is something we *want* to encourage..." ([“Votes cast” should include votes on deleted contributions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/165773)) See also: [Could it be that 124 posts I upvoted are all deleted?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5442/31260) @Shog9 I think I already tested that

Comment: @Shog9 not sure I quite have the tools to do this with my current levels of privilege. If you give me a diamond, I'll see about voting on 249 posts, delete them all, and then voting on one more and see if works. There might be some collateral damage, but that's just QA leaving the system in an inconsistent state... nothing a quick restore can't fix.

Comment: Shame you don't have 10K on SO; would be pretty easy to find 249 posts that were about to get deleted anyway...

Comment: @Shog9 that would actually mean making one's eyes bleed with php or regex posts. This would mean *far* too much brandy cider and I might have to start accepting Haskell into my heart.  ... That said, you don't need 10k, just 125 and find the necessary number where a single vote on the poorly asked +1 score rep question that was closed a month ago with no action since.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I just want to verify that if I vote on exactly 250 posts in seven days and happen to delete one of them too, that its the 250 votes that count, not the 249 that are still in the system.

Yes, it's the 250. Here's the relevant comment chain from the Google Docs hat spreadsheet:

[image: Me: I'm inclined to count votes on posts that were later deleted]

Answer (score 7):

For your postscript: this hat is for standard upvotes and downvotes on questions and answers. That's also the usual case for anywhere we talk about a "number of votes" without specifying the type either explicitly or by context. I'm sure someone will now dig up a weird exception and point it out in a comment, but that's the general safe bet.

I'll have to leave your main question to someone more familiar with the exact implementation details.