# Does delete votes count for "vote early vote often" hat?

Tags: support, voting, vote-to-close, winter-bash-2015

Let me keep it simple. Related to "vote early vote often" hat, what's the exact criteria?

> "cast a total of 250 votes on any seven consecutive UTC days"

is it

- up, down and delete votes taken together?

or

- up and down votes taken together?

Any clarification?

---

<sup>P.S -</sup>

<sup>1. [My MSO question on this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271030/244062)</sup>

<sup>2. [I am not asking whether refunded votes from deleted content gets counted or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271030/244062)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are not asking about standard votes on content that gets deleted, my answer to that question you linked also happens to cover the situation you *are* asking about:

> this hat is for standard upvotes and downvotes on questions and answers. That's also the usual case for anywhere we talk about a "number of votes" without specifying the type either explicitly or by context

Comment: Yes, I think that clarifies the point. Thanks.

Comment: Do I have to vote exactly 250 times or is 250 a lower limit?

Comment: @G-man Lower limit.

Comment: @Pops thanks for the reply, but in the last week I voted 265 times on MSE but I don't have the hat.

Comment: @G-man it looks to me like you did vote a lot of times, but you retracted a few of those votes, putting you _just_ under the threshold after all was said and done. If you vote on a post and the post gets deleted, the vote still counts, but if you cast a vote and then remove/delete the vote itself, it doesn't count (I'm pretty sure).