# Are downvotes on deleted posts counted in the profile vote count?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Many of my downvotes are on spam and low quality posts, and these quite often end up deleted.

So when I downvote and the post is deleted shortly after, is the downvote still counted in this number?

[image]

Comment: Seems yes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/299342